# Is there a new portals feed for Ingress?

Tags: ingress

Is there any way to receive information on new portals in an specific area in Ingress? For example, a RSS feed or similar that reports on new portals being accepted 10KM around a point in the map. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a portal is accepted, you receive a mail saying you will see it in a near future.

But after that, no other notifications, you'll have to check your scanner when you're near a future portal location or look on the intel map every day ;-)

EDIT: new portals were added today (25/01/2013) and nothing inform us (except seeing many people running everywhere with their phone in hands to capture new portals before the other faction ;) ).

Comment: In my area only very few people got an email.

Answer (score 2):

We have a google+ community for our region and people post there intel on new portals etc.

Another way is just check ingress intel map regularly.